# mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to, QT project fails during unit tests

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm in the middle of submitting a QT project, but the automated unit testing on my course is giving me the following error. I've been trying to figure out what the issue and I can't figure out why. The full error is as follows.

```
/usr/local/bin/moc -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_TESTLIB_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR='"/submission-repo/student/12/timer"' --include ./moc_predefs.h -I/usr/local/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/submission-repo/student/12/timer -I/usr/local/include/QtWidgets -I/usr/local/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/include/QtTest -I/usr/local/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/c++/5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5 -I/usr/include/c++/5/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include tst_timer.cpp -o tst_timer.moc
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_TESTLIB_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR='"/submission-repo/student/12/timer"' -I. -isystem /usr/local/include/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/local/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/local/include/QtTest -isystem /usr/local/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/usr/local/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o tst_timer.o tst_timer.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_TESTLIB_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR='"/submission-repo/student/12/timer"' -I. -isystem /usr/local/include/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/local/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/local/include/QtTest -isystem /usr/local/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/usr/local/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_TESTLIB_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_TESTCASE_BUILDDIR='"/submission-repo/student/12/timer"' -I. -isystem /usr/local/include/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/local/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/local/include/QtTest -isystem /usr/local/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/usr/local/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -o tst_timer tst_timer.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/usr/local/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Test -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `Stopwatch::isRunning()'
mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::on_stopButton_clicked()':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `Stopwatch::isRunning()'
mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `Stopwatch::Stopwatch()'
mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::update()':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x592): undefined reference to `Stopwatch::isRunning()'
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x5c5): undefined reference to `Stopwatch::getTime()'
mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `Stopwatch::start()'
mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::on_stopButton_clicked()':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `Stopwatch::stop()'
mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::on_resetButton_clicked()':
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `Stopwatch::reset()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:245: recipe for target 'tst_timer' failed
make: *** [tst_timer] Error 1
```

Here are my files.

`mainwindow.hh`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HH
#define MAINWINDOW_HH

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include "stopwatch.hh"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    // Normally this member should be in private part of the
    // class, but due to the automated tests it must be more
    // accessible.
    QTimer* timer;

private slots:
    // Add your slots here
    void on_startButton_clicked();
    void on_stopButton_clicked();
    void on_resetButton_clicked();
    void update();

signals:

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Stopwatch* watch;
    // Add other necessary members here
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_HH
```

`stopwatch.hh`

```
#ifndef STOPWATCH_HH
#define STOPWATCH_HH

#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QTime>

class Stopwatch
{
public:
    explicit Stopwatch();
    void start();
    void stop();
    void reset();
    qint64 getTime();
    bool isRunning();
    void setRunning(bool running);


private:
    bool mRunning;
    qint64 mTotalTime;
    qint64 mTempTime;
    QDateTime mStartTime;
    QTime *time;
signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // STOPWATCH_HH
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.hh"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    watch(new Stopwatch())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto lcdpalette = new QPalette;
    lcdpalette->setColor(QPalette::Background, QColor(0, 0, 0));
    lcdpalette->setColor(QPalette::Base, QColor(255, 160, 122));
    lcdpalette->setColor(QPalette::AlternateBase, QColor(255, 160, 122));


    ui->lcdNumberMin->setPalette(*lcdpalette);
    ui->lcdNumberMin->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    ui->lcdNumberSec->setPalette(*lcdpalette);
    ui->lcdNumberSec->setAutoFillBackground(true);

    QObject::connect(ui->startButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
                     this, &MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked);
    QObject::connect(ui->stopButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
                     this, &MainWindow::on_stopButton_clicked);
    QObject::connect(ui->resetButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
                     this, &MainWindow::on_resetButton_clicked);

     timer = new QTimer(this);
     connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
     timer->start(1);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete watch;
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    if(not (watch->isRunning()))
    {
        watch->start();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_stopButton_clicked()
{
    if(watch->isRunning())
    {
        watch->stop();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_resetButton_clicked()
{
    ui->lcdNumberMin->display(00);
    ui->lcdNumberSec->display(00);
    watch->reset();
}


// Triggers every 10 milliseconds (every hundredth of a second)
// Updates the time displayed on the stopwatch.
void MainWindow::update()
{
    if(watch->isRunning())
    {
        qint64 time = watch->getTime();
        int hour = time / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        int minutes = (time / 1000 / 60) - (hour * 60);
        int seconds = (time / 1000) - (minutes * 60);

        if(seconds < 10) {
            ui->lcdNumberSec->display(QStringLiteral("0%1").arg(seconds));
        }
        else {
            ui->lcdNumberSec->display(QStringLiteral("%1").arg(seconds));
        }
        if(minutes < 10) {
            ui->lcdNumberMin->display(QStringLiteral("0%1").arg(minutes));
        }
        else {
            ui->lcdNumberMin->display(QStringLiteral("%1").arg(minutes));
        }
    }
}
```

`stopwatch.cpp`

```
#include "stopwatch.hh"

// Default constructor
Stopwatch::Stopwatch() :
    mRunning(false),
    mTotalTime(0),
    mTempTime(0)
{
}

// Starts the stopwatch.
// Instantiates the start time and declares the watch to be running.
void Stopwatch::start()
{
    mStartTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    mRunning = true;
}

// Pauses the stopwatch.
// Saves the current time and declares the watch to not be running.
void Stopwatch::stop()
{
    mTotalTime += mTempTime;
    mRunning = false;
}

// Resets the stopwatch.
// Resets the saved time and declares the watch to not be running.
void Stopwatch::reset()
{
    mTotalTime = 0;
    mRunning = false;
}

// Returns whether the stopwatch is running.
bool Stopwatch::isRunning()
{
    return mRunning;
}

// Sets the state of the stopwatch (running/not running)
void Stopwatch::setRunning(bool running)
{
    mRunning = running;
}

// Returns the current time of the running stopwatch
qint64 Stopwatch::getTime()
{
    mTempTime = mStartTime.msecsTo(QDateTime::currentDateTime());
    qint64 time = mTotalTime + mTempTime;
    return time;
}
```

`timer.pro`

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = timer
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
        stopwatch.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.hh \
        stopwatch.hh

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

I've cleaned and rebuilt project multiple times and it hasn't solved anything.

Comment: Do you have a cpp for the stopwatch? Not seeing it in what you provided. The error is saying that the functions aren't defined.

Comment: I do, I'll add that.

Comment: It is also not part of your compiler command line.

Comment: @ChrisMM I have no control over the compiler commands, so what are my options here?

Comment: @cyberbemon share your .pro...

Comment: Well, you could move the implementation of stopwatch into mainwindow.cpp, or in the stopwatch header. If using a tool like cmake, qmake, etc., share that.

Comment: @eyllanesc it's an alternative to `!` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/not

Comment: @eyllanesc added the `.pro`file.

Comment: @eyllanesc it's `mainwindow.hh`. Ive updated the post.

Comment: @cyberbemon remove  `signals:

public slots:` in stopwatch.hh